# Trying to align reference genome to STAR

Tags: rna-seq

I am trying to set up a reference genome on STAR 2.7.3a so that I can map the reads from my RNA-Seq to it.

Here's the code I use:

```
STAR --runThreadN 4--runMode genomeGenerate--genomeDir /media/bigData/Valentin/Software/referenceGenomeforSTAR--genomeDir /media/bigData/Valentin/ReferenceGenome--genomeFastaFiles /media/bigData/Valentin/ReferenceGenome/Homo_sapiens.GRCh38.ncrna.fa /media/bigData/Valentin/ReferenceGenome/Homo_sapiens.GRCh38.dna.primary_assembly.fa--sjdbGTFfile /media/bigData/Valentin/ReferenceGenome--sjbdOverhang 100
```

EXITING because of fatal input

> ERROR: could not open readFilesIn=Read1
>
> Jan 24 15:44:39 ...... FATAL ERROR, exiting

Does anyone know what readFilesIn=Read1 means?

Thank you